# How to code this dynamic table from a web application called omni calculator (on salary conversions) as an org table in Emacs?

Tags: org-mode, spreadsheet

I like this [application](https://www.omnicalculator.com/finance/salary-to-hourly). I would like to build something similar but as a table inside a `.org` file.

This is an interesting and easy-to-understand particular case. But I would use this kind of approach for multiple situations.

Something like, the user types the hour value:

```lisp
Hours per week: 40

    | Hour | Day | Week  | Month | Year    |
    |------+-----+-------+-------+---------|
    |   50 |     |       |       |         |
```

And, boom, all other cells are filled:

```lisp
Hours per week: 40

    | Hour | Day | Week  | Month | Year    |
    |------+-----+-------+-------+---------|
    |   50 | 400 | 2,000 | 8,667 | 104,000 |
```

I suppose this is possible with an Elisp code snippet.

What would that code be?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [org spreadsheet formulas](https://orgmode.org/manual/The-Spreadsheet.html) to do this.

```
| Hour | Day | Week | Month | Year |
|------+-----+------+-------+------|
|   50 |     |      |       |      |
#+TBLFM: $2=$1*8::$3=$2*5::$4=$3*4::$5=$3*52
```

With point anywhere in the `TBLFM` line, pressing `C-c C-c` generates the following:

```
| Hour | Day | Week | Month |   Year |
|------+-----+------+-------+--------|
|   50 | 400 | 2000 |  8000 | 104000 |
#+TBLFM: $2=$1*8::$3=$2*5::$4=$3*4::$5=$3*52
```

You'll want to update the values in the formula to suit your definition of a week, month year etc. It's up to you which values you want to hard-code in the formula, and which you want to include in the table to allow for easier updating.

See the linked manual page for more details and options.